# Are angularJS directive names unique (or not)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Found this [amazing video](https://youtu.be/TUYnK3PKpsw?t=7m1s) that explains angularJS directives. However, there is one thing that i heard that i have a question about.

"In angular directive names are not unique so we need to support the fact that for each name there might be several directive factories."

^ I am not sure about this. Is the presenter saying the same directive name can be redeclared twice (with different factory functions)? Something like the below code.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<h1>hello</h1>'
  }
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<h1>hi</h1>'
  }
});
```

However, code like this seems to be throwing an error.. It would be great if someone could clarify a.) Does angularJS store multiple factory functions for each directive?, and b.) If this is possible how and when would we do something like this?

Comment: What is the error it throws? Ive never done it but it was my understanding the last declared service, directive etc overwrites any others declared with the same name. If you import two separate modules that have the same service for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [angular tips](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/tip-directives-with-the-same-name/) you can have 2 directives with the same name and they will work together. 
In the comments it is mentioned that you cant have isolated scopes or require a controller.

I tried to use 2 directive with the same name and different template and the first template was used, no errors ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/2772/)).

```
<div ng-app="ui.directives">
   <my-d></my-d>
</div>


var dirs = angular.module('ui.directives', []);
dirs.directive('myD',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'hey'
    };
  }
);
dirs.directive('myD',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: 'hello',
    };
  }
);
```

Whats your error? try adding a jsfiddle

Comment: I saw this error angular-1.0.0.js:5525 Error: Multiple directives [myD, myD] asking for template on: <my-d> but i guess the code works anyway. Thanks...